# facebook like on twenty eleven

Tags: facebook, theme-twenty-eleven

I'm using the twenty-eleven theme, and want a Facebook-like button.

I insert the code into `content-single.php` as follows:

At the beginning:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

And then, inside the loop, after the call to `the_content()`:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

The buttons appear fine in FF, Chrome. and IE9, and even IE7(!). But in IE8 - they don't appear at all. The `div` is there, but it doesn't get filled with the `iframe`.

When I insert the same code in a twenty-ten theme, it appears fine in IE8.

Has anyone run into this problem? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up taking the iframe code instead of the HTML5 code I had taken before, and that solved the problem...